# The remote end hung up unexpectedly while git fetch on network shared drive

Tags: git, network-share

Getting remote end hung up unexpectedly while using git fetch in my network shared drive although git clone is working but getting this issue with **git fetch**

Comment: Please provide exact command input and output. One possibility that you have multiple remotes and one of them is failing.

Comment: command Input:  git fetch --tags --progress --repolink +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10       and Output Error:   fatal: early EOF
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: index-pack failed
org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:161)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:154)

Comment: This looks like you're hitting all remotes. You can update the question to include the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: getting repository url for push and fetch. While I am performing git clone it is working fine but getting it with git fetch.Although git fetch is working for my local drives but not for the network shared one.